# Why OVAL deprecated SQL format?

Tags: vulnerability-management

I'm a developer to develop a vulnerability management program. I'm currently analyzing OVAL. Do you know why OVAL deprecated the SQL format?

I read through the following article,
http://making-security-measurable.1364806.n2.nabble.com/Proposal-Deprecate-SQL-format-td20835.html

Why would you be able to find more specific information concerning whether to abandon SQL here?

Do you know if and how you can find?
Buttner, Andrew, "`<Oval SQL = 'false'>`", presentation, The MITRE Corporation, Oct 2003.

Comment: because XML is a more standard and more useable format

Comment: @schroeder thank you but i want to more detail infomation.because my current project program is sqlite embeed ):

Comment: I'm not sure why that's relevant. OVAL data isn't available in SQL format and there are lots of converters for XML into SQL. Why do you want to know why they depreciated it 12 years ago?

Comment: By analyzing the history of the oval I would like to learn the know-how in this product I am in charge.

I developed the current system, which was created to see the oval. And vulnerability information has been gathered using sql format and sqlite. So do that depressed oval in the 12 years I want to know why so that for any reason.


If I have seen further it is by standing on the shoulders of Giants.

Comment: I think the reason to switch to XML is 'obvious'. It's much easier to process and display and it allows for expansion without needing to redo the entire SQL schema. I think if you looked at the reason why XML is better, in general, then you'll have your answer.